# Can't use hook inside Higher order component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript, react-custom-hooks, high-order-component

I want to use a useState hook inside my HOC, but that prevents the component from being rendered

here is my component

```
import WithAccessControl from "components/HOC/AccessControl";

function GoalPage(props: any) {
    return <div>Who stole my goals?</div>;
}
export default WithAccessControl(GoalPage);
```

and this is my HOC which the component is passed to:

```
import React from "react";

const WithAccessControl = (Component: React.FC) => {
    debugger;
    [state, setState] = React.useState();
    return Component;
};

export default WithAccessControl;
```

When I don't use `useState()` inside my HOC, It works fine, but after adding so, It just doesn't render without any console errors, and after adding a debugger to the code I noticed that the webpack is throwing an error.

---

This is how webpack throws the error from debugger :

```js
__webpack_require__.i.push((options) => {
    const originalFactory = options.factory;
    options.factory = function (moduleObject, moduleExports, webpackRequire) {
        __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.setup(options.id);
        try {
            originalFactory.call(this, moduleObject, moduleExports, webpackRequire);
        } finally {
            if (typeof Promise !== 'undefined' && moduleObject.exports instanceof Promise) {
                options.module.exports = options.module.exports.then(
                    (result) => {
                        __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(options.id);
                        return result;
                    },
                    (reason) => {
                        __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(options.id);
                        return Promise.reject(reason);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(options.id)
            }
        }
    };
})
```

what is causing the error and WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot use a hook in normal functions, only in components. Your HOC is not a component, but a wrapper method that returns a component.

What you want would be something like (*simple version*)

```
import React from "react";

const WithAccessControl = (Component: React.FC) => {
    debugger;
    return (props) => {
      const [state, setState] = React.useState();
      
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
};

export default WithAccessControl;
```

Comment: React Hook "React.useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

Comment: @Rocky does it still throw this warning if you change the first letter of the HOC to lowercase as in `withAccessControl` ?

Comment: no it doesn't warn me anymore

Answer (score 1):

Once changing "WithAccessControl" to lowercase "withAccessControl" it worked for me.
Start with lowercase W.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).